# iphone uipickerview with images

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

it's possible add as item in the uipickerview some images/icons instead of text?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes it is absolutely possible. u need to handle pickerView delegate method

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

here you simply return custom view(could be anything UIImage UILabel)

and set userInteractionEnable property to no for customize view..