# iPhone Picker Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a double picker with just plain text.  On one of the columns, I want to place a pic in the picker.

For example the picker is picking the number of people, so the first item I want to be a picture of a person, then the numbers 1,2,3,4.. and so on.

Any examples, tutorials on how to do this.  I can't seem to find any examples online, and I know it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a custom view for component. Look at this link -

[iphone uipickerview with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366974/iphone-uipickerview-with-images)